# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable in Kubernates cluster Spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I run in Kubernetes 3 pods my spring boot app images.
Then I want to make routing to the website using ingress. When I open the browser and access the website, I get an error 503 like images below. So, how do I fix this error?
[image]

kind-config.yml:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    kubeadmConfigPatches:
      - |
        kind: InitConfiguration
        nodeRegistration:
          kubeletExtraArgs:
            node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 80
        hostPort: 8888
        protocol: TCP
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
```

deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: schoolapplication
  labels:
    app: schoolapplication
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: schoolapplication
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: schoolapplication
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: schoolapplication
          image: shatovdv/schoolapplication:1.0.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: DATASOURCE_HOST
              value: 172.18.0.1
            - name: spring.mvc.servlet.path
              value: /schoolapplication
```

service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: schoolapplication
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: schoolapplication
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

ingress.yml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-school
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /schoolapplication
            backend:
              service:
                name: schoolapplication
                port:
                  number: 80
```